# Access denied problem in AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to parse a web page into my page, so i prefer AJAX in my code.
While using the AJAX it showing "Access denied" - before fetching the specified page. The page doesn't consider any login information.

Even though i cant able to get the page of google too..

Please guide me to how to use the AJAX so for

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can send `XMLHttpRequest`s only to your domain.
if your site is `example.com` you can send `XMLHttpRequest`s only to `example.com`.
Firefox 3 supports cross-domain requests but you need to send `Access-Control` first.

The solution is to send a request to your domain and fetch cross-domain content via some server language (Java, PHP, Python, etc.)

Comment: loading data by inserting a script node gets around the x-domain problem too, at least for GET requests

Comment: not script but iframe in this case, (praveenjayapal needs html), but this may bring other problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a hack to retrieve data through a CSS include http://nb.io/hacks/csshttprequest